# Dynamic SQL in SQL Server - how to?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

My question is about dynamic SQL. I have two tables

- customers (custid, fn_name, Ln_name)
- vendors (vendor_id, Custid, ordernum, orderdate)

And also I have other tables

- table (tableid(pk), name)
- table_col (colid(pk), tableid(fk), colname)
- table_keys (key_id, tableid, key_col_name)

Now if user selects any column from the `table_col` tables, dynamically I need to get column names and dynamically identify the join from the `table_keys` based on the name match.

Answer (score 0):

Could be somethings like this

```
 select 
    t.name
  , c.colname
  , case k.key_col_name when not  null then 'X' else '' end as iskey 
 from table_col as c
 left join table_keys as k on k.key_col_name = c.colname
 inner join table as t on t.tableid = c.tableid
 where t.name in  ('customers', 'vendors');
```